# What is the difference of immutable and mutable variables?

Tags: immutability

I have read almost every definition of immutable/mutable variables on the internet but as a beginner I just do not grasp it fully so I was wondering if someone could really explain it in layman terms.

Immutable variables (or objects) in any programming language is what I understand when you cannot change the value of that variable after it has been assigned a value. For example, I am using the Haskell programming language, and I write:

```
let x = 5
```

Since Haskell has immutable variables, x can never have any other value than 5. So if I after that line of code write:

```
x = 2
```

I have in fact not changed the value of x but made a new variable with the same name, which will now be the one that is referenced when I call x, so after both lines of code I can only reach an x with the value of 2.

But what is a mutable variable then, and what programming languages have it? This is where it gets foggy for me. Because when people say mutable variable, they are obviously referring to a variable or object which value you *can* indeed change after it has been assigned an initial value.

Does this mean that if you have a mutable variable you actually manipulate *that place in the computers memory* for that variable, and in case of immutable variable you cannot manipulate that place in the computers memory or what?

I don't know how to explain my question any further, as I said, I understand that mutable = can change value of variable after initial value assignment, immutable = cannot. I get the definition. But I don't understand what it actually means in terms of what is going on "behind the scenes". I guess I am looking for easy examples on actual mutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with immutability

```
let x = 5
x = 2
```

This is **reassignment** and definitely not allowed in Haskell

---

First let's look at a regular `let` assignment

```
Prelude> let x = 5 in x
5
it :: Num a => a
```

You can bind `x` using `let`, and rebind a *new* `x` in a nested `let` – this effectively *shadows* the outer `x`

```
Prelude> let x = 5 in let x = 2 in x
2
it :: Num a => a
```

Remember a `let` is basically a lambda

```
Prelude> (\x -> x) 5
5
it :: Num a => a
```

And of course a lambda can return a lambda; illustrates shadowing agian

```
Prelude> (\x -> (\x -> x)) 5 2
2
it :: Num a => a
```

Answer (score 1):

**Mutable** respectively **immutable** does not concern the *variables* but the *values*. Note: one also says the *type* is *(im-)mutable*.

For instance if the value is of an immutable type StudentCard, with fields ID and Name, then after creation the fields no longer can be changed. On a name change the student card must be reissued, a new StudentCard must be created.

A more elementary *immutable* type is String in java. Assigning the same value to two variables is no problem as one variable may not change the shared value. Sharing a mutable value could be dangerous.

A commont *mutable* type is the array in java and others. Sharing an array, say storing an array parameter in a field, risks that somewhere else the array content is changed inadvertently changing your field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a shorthand answer to your question would be that a Mutable variable that holds a value that you would later want to be adjusted.

Depending on the language you're using is its method.

In Kotlin val and var are used to declare variables.

val is a constant while var is adjustable.